# Remove almost identical data frame rows by condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a data frame with a number of almost identical rows. What I need is to write a code that would allow choosing one of the rows within a pair (or group of 3 or 4) of rows which are similar in Name, Surname, V1, and P1 but differ in V2 and P2, and then delete the unwanted row. Which row needs to be maintained would be specified by the following condition: if P1 = P2, the row has to be kept, if P1 < P2 the row has to be deleted if P1 > P2 then the row with the largest P2 should be kept.

```
id   Name  Surname     V1         P1       V2        P2
15  John    Smith     0.80        4       0.75        2    
16  John    Smith     0.80        4       1.00        3    
17  John    Smith     0.80        5       0.75        2    
18  John    Smith     0.80        5       1.00        3    
19  John    Smith     0.75        2       0.75        2    
20  John    Smith     0.75        2       1.00        3
```

The output I expect would look as follows:

```
id  Name  Surname     V1          P1       V2        P2
16  John    Smith     0.80        4       1.00        3    
18  John    Smith     0.80        5       1.00        3    
19  John    Smith     0.75        2       0.75        2
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Extended data set

```
id    Name Surname V1     P1    V2      P2
194   Lisa  Paul   0,1    1     0,2      1
195   Lisa  Paul   0,1    1     0,4      5
196   Lisa  Paul   0,1    4     0,5      1
197   Lisa  Paul   0,1    4     0,1      5
198   Lisa  Paul   0,1    2     0,1      1
199   Lisa  Paul   0,1    2     0,4      5
201   Lisa  Paul   0,1    3     0,2      1
202   Lisa  Paul   0,1    3     0,1      5
203   Lisa  Paul   0,1    5     0,3      1
204   Lisa  Paul   0,1    5     0,2      5
205   Lisa  Paul   0,1    6     0,2      1
206   Lisa  Paul   0,1    6     0,1      5
```

Comment: While your conditions on P1 and P2 are clear, the rest isn't. Supposedly Name and Surname have to be the same. What about V1 and V2, exactly?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment.  I skipped this info because the pair is determined by P1. So V1 would be the same in each pair. V2 could be different. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with your example data it would seem that the following works:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(Name, Surname, P1) %>%
  filter(P2 == max(P2[P1 >= P2]))
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   Name, Surname, P1 [6]
#      id Name  Surname    V1    P1    V2    P2
#   <int> <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1   194 Lisa  Paul      0.1     1   0.2     1
# 2   196 Lisa  Paul      0.1     4   0.5     1
# 3   198 Lisa  Paul      0.1     2   0.1     1
# 4   201 Lisa  Paul      0.1     3   0.2     1
# 5   204 Lisa  Paul      0.1     5   0.2     5
# 6   206 Lisa  Paul      0.1     6   0.1     5
```

For each unique group of Name, Surname, and P1 I keep those rows that have the largest P2 out of all those P2 that are no greater than the corresponding P1.

Comment: @KateTol, does it answer your question?

Comment: Julius, thanks a lot for your answer! It works. But when applied to the extended data set ( I added it to the original post) it leaves only rows for periods 1, 5, and 6. Although periods 2,3,4 also need to be kept in the data. What could be done with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KateTol, but when P1 is 2, then in both cases P1<P2, and your question says "if P1 < P2 the row has to be deleted". So what's the full criterion then?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that the problem might be that when P1 is equal 2, 3, and 4  they all are larger than P2 in one case and smaller in the second. So that, for instance, when R has to take the largest number (max P2) the resulting row contains  P1 < P2 which means that it has to be deleted. Does it make any sense? So basically what is needed, as far as I understand, is that if max (P2) > P1 it has somehow to take the row which is max (P2) which is not > 1.

Comment: @KateTol, ah right, I see where I was wrong. Perhaps now it looks good?